# Undefined class DateTime in PHPStorm

Tags: php, datetime, yii2

I want to use class `DateTime` but `PHPStorm` says me that `"Undefined class DateTime"` and my PHP version is `5.5.9-1`.
I'm using PHPStorm version `2016.1` and i'm working with `Yii2 framework` (if it'll give you any useful information). So how can i use with correct lint default PHP classes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use backslash `\DateTime` or add `use DateTime;`