# cant parse DateTime::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel, datetime-format, php-carbon

I have a @foreach on my blade:

```
@foreach
{{ $value-> StartDate}}
@endforeach
```

the StartDate is currently displaying like 'sept 2020 12:00:00AM'
I want it do be formatted as 'dd/mm/yy'/'d/m/y' essentially like 23-09-2020 or 23/09/2020

I have tried

```
{{ $value->StartDate->format('d,m,y')}}
```

and

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($value->StartDate)->format('d,m,y') }}
```

and also changing 'd,m,y' to 'dd,mm,yyyy' etc but I ma getting error. the main error I get is

> Could not parse 'Sep 15 2020 12:00:00:AM': DateTime::__construct():
> Failed to parse time string (Sep 15 2020 12:00:00:AM) at position 20
> (:): Unexpected character

is there a proper way to change the formatting?

**UPDATE with more detail :**

Im attempting to change how some dates are displayed on my blade file. they are coming from the sql database as 'Sep 16 2020 12:00:00:AM' i want them to display as '16-09-2020' Below is the attempt I have made, however I am still getting this error

> Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. The separation symbol could not be found Trailing data

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this error?

my model :

```
    class HomeModel extends Entity
{
    protected $dates = [
        'StartDate',
    ];

    public static function findBy(
        \DateTime $StartDate,
        \DateTime $EndDate
    ): array
    {
        $params = [
            $StartDate,
            $EndDate,

        ];
        return self::hydrate(DB::select('EXEC Table @StartDate = ?, @EndDate = ?',
            $params
        ));
    }
}
```

my controller :

```
   class Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->input('StartDate') && !$request->input('EndDate')) {
            $StartTime = Carbon::now()->subDays(8);
            $EndTime = Carbon::now();
        } else {
            $StartTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('StartDate'));
            $EndTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('EndDate'));
        }
        $data = HomeModel::findBy(
            Carbon::parse($StartTime),
            Carbon::parse($EndTime)
        );

        return view ('home', compact('data'));
    }
```

my blade :

```
    <tbody class="list">
                    @foreach($data as $value)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="end-time">
                                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value->StartDate)->format('d/m/Y')}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

I have attempted the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030421/14106443) but it returns the error of

> DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

which was expected as I am trying to get the dates from an array. my attempts of turning the array into a string were also futile. **Does anyone know of any php functions for formatting dates in an array?**

Comment: `12:00:00:AM` has an extra colon between the 00 and AM. You'll need to either fix that or change how you're parsing it. Carbon has a [createFromFormat](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) function to specify the format.

Comment: the format from the database table is 'm-d-Y H:i:s', it displays that way,  would I still need to use createFromFormat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution. There wasnt an issue with my code but where I was running it.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($value->StartDate)->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

works great in the blade and will format it correctly. the issue I had was I was not working withing laradock, which is why I was getting the error of

> Could not parse 'Sep 15 2020 12:00:00:AM': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Sep 15 2020 12:00:00:AM) at position 20 (:): Unexpected character

After running `docker-compose up`  in the terminal, I stopped getting errors and the dates were formatted correctly.
My takeaway is that if you stumble apon this error, check your development area.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the PHP `createFromFormat` function?

```
<?php

$date='sept 2020 12:00:00AM';   //dd/mm/yy
$new= \DateTime::createFromFormat('M Y H:i:sA', $date )->format('d/m/Y'); 
echo $new;
```

Or you can parse the date as below.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Check the [demo](https://3v4l.org/pj8XV)

Comment: when I attempt this I get ' udefined class of 'DateTime' '

Comment: would this be in the model or in the controller, im currently attempting it in the controller

Comment: edited answer, use backword slash. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562376/undefined-class-datetime-in-phpstorm

Comment: where you want to convert your date, if you convert it in the controller then it whould be in controller

Comment: I'd like to convert the dates on the blade, can I still you this?

Comment: yes you can use `@php $new = DateTime::createFromFormat('M Y H:i:sA', $date )->format('d/m/Y') @endphp`

Comment: sorry the answer was not helpful